# How to run serenity with cucumber without maven or gradle

Tags: cucumber, junit5, serenity-bdd

I am trying to run Serenity-bdd with Cucumber and JUNIT5 from a main method but cannot figure out how to do it.
Serenity has a starter where they described how to create a project with maven or gradle, but there is no option to run the tests without both. I have a test project (the tests are within src/main/java) and would like to build it and run the tests from a jar file.

Comment: Maybe it helps someone: https://github.com/petrac-daniel/serenity-cucumber-junit5-demo